# What is animating the SLDS Tree chevron

Tags: lightning-design-system

The Lightning Design System includes a [Tree](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/#flavor-base-expanded) component. Each node in the tree can have a chevron svg icon indicating if it is expanded or collapsed.

[image: Expanded and collapsed nodes]

Regardless of the node state it always appears to use the `/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevronright` icon.

How is the lightning design system animating the SVG chevron's on tree nodes?

In the example if I change the `aria-expanded` attribute in the DOM on the corresponding `li` it rotates into a down arrow. Change it back to false and it rotates back.

The only active scripting I can see on the page is something about Raven config. It isn't clear to me if or how this is animating the svg icon. It may or may not be relavant.

I'm using the SLDS 2.1.3 in a Visualforce page and I'm not getting the same animation or rotation occuring.

Using something like the following to toggle the `li` attribute.

```
document.getElementById('tree0-node1').setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it in the GitHub [source](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/5e561ed89fbb0b049be57755dd6daa89463e14de/ui/components/trees/flavors/base/_index.scss#L68). It is animated and rotated via the CSS.

```
  [aria-expanded="false"] > .#{$css-prefix}tree__item > .#{$css-prefix}button[aria-controls] > .#{$css-prefix}button__icon,
  [aria-expanded="false"] > .#{$css-prefix}tree__item > .#{$css-prefix}button[aria-controls] > span > .#{$css-prefix}button__icon {
    transition: $duration-promptly transform ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  [aria-expanded="true"] > .#{$css-prefix}tree__item > .#{$css-prefix}button[aria-controls] > .#{$css-prefix}button__icon,
  [aria-expanded="true"] > .#{$css-prefix}tree__item > .#{$css-prefix}button[aria-controls] > span > .#{$css-prefix}button__icon {
    transition: $duration-promptly transform ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
```

When it actually comes out in my Visualforce page the CSS is:

```
  .myscopingclass .slds-tree [aria-expanded="false"] > .slds-tree__item > .slds-button[aria-controls] > .slds-button__icon,
  .myscopingclass .slds-tree [aria-expanded="false"] > .slds-tree__item > .slds-button[aria-controls] > span > .slds-button__icon {
    transition: 0.2s transform ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(0deg); }
  .myscopingclass .slds-tree [aria-expanded="true"] > .slds-tree__item > .slds-button[aria-controls] > .slds-button__icon,
  .myscopingclass .slds-tree [aria-expanded="true"] > .slds-tree__item > .slds-button[aria-controls] > span > .slds-button__icon {
    transition: 0.2s transform ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(90deg); }
```

The problem with my Visualforce page was a missing `aria-controls` attribute on the button that the CSS selector required.

Doh! To be fair to the SLDS, the requirement for this is right there in the [documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/#overview):

> In our example, we are using a chevron icon on tree branches to help indicate to the user what action clicking the tree branch will perform, whether opening or closing it. The effect of rotating the icon 90° to indicate open/closed status is achieved by applying the ARIA attribute `aria-controls` to the button the icon is contained within. The value of the `aria-controls` attribute should be the ID of the group that clicking the button will affect.

Comment: do i need any javascript to achieve interactions like collapse and expand?

Comment: @BalayesuChilakalapudi Yes, I used JavaScript to toggle the `aria-expanded` attribute between true and false when the node was clicked.